# Replace url parameter without changing the others

Tags: javascript

I want to dynamically change a specific parameter in the navigation bar.
I have this url and want to change "pedro" by "max":

`http://mywebsite.com/?par1=mynameis&par2=pedro&par3=nicetomeetyou`

By using this, it removes all my parameters.

```
hello = "max"
window.history.replaceState(null, null, "?par2="+hello);
```

This is what I want:

```
http://mywebsite.com/?par1=mynameis&par2=max&par3=nicetomeetyou
```

and not

```
http://mywebsite.com/?par1=mynameis&par2=max
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```js
const hello = 'max';
// let url = new URL(location.href); // from location.href
let url = new URL(`http://mywebsite.com/?par1=mynameis&par2=pedro&par3=nicetomeetyou`); // from string
url.searchParams.set('par2',hello); // change ONE parameter
console.log(url.searchParams.toString());
window.history.replaceState(null, null, `?${url.searchParams.toString()}`);
```

I prefer to start from the full URL but you can use the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instead

```js
const hello = 'max';
// let sp = new URLSearchParams(location.search); // from location.search
let sp = new URLSearchParams(`?par1=mynameis&par2=pedro&par3=nicetomeetyou`); 
sp.set('par2',hello); // change ONE parameter
console.log(sp.toString());
window.history.replaceState(null, null, `?${sp.toString()}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `URLSearchParams`:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); // Creates search params object
params.set('par2', hello); // Set par2 to new value
window.history.replaceState(null, null, params.toString()); // Replace url
```

Comment: This seems to replace a larger part of the URL with the params instead of just updating the intended param.  `https://whatever.com/foo/bar/baz?par1=mynameis&par2=max&par3=nicetomeetyou` becomes
`https://whatever.com/foo/bar/par1=mynameis&par2=foobar&par3=nicetomeetyou` - I loose the `baz` portion of the URL and the `?`.   I tested this by adding the QS params to this page and running it in the console.

Comment: @FiniteLooper sounds unlikely: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/btna3o1h/

Answer (score 0):

This may not be ideal, but it works.

```js
var newpar2 = "max"
var newQueryStr = window.location.search.replace(/^(.+&par2=).+?(&.+)$/, `$1${newpar2}$2`)
window.history.replaceState(null, null, newQueryStr);
```

Comment: You are correct. Not ideal ;)

Comment: Yes, your answer is much better. I was not aware of the `URL` object.  I assume you can just pass `window.location` into that object to build a full `URL` object for the current url?

Comment: Indeed. Or use the URLSearchParams and pass in location.search